# ArangoDB upgrade from 2.7 to 2.8 (not to 3.x)?

Tags: version, upgrade, arangodb

I want to upgrade arangodb server from 2.7 to 2.8.
I've read I can do that with `--upgrade`
My question is if `--upgrade` upgrades to the last released version (`3.x`) or to `2.8`. I don't want to upgrade it to 3.x just to 2.8
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `--upgrade` command will upgrade the "old" data directory to the version of ArangoDB you have installed.
So if you install 2.8 and run `--upgrade` you will get a 2.8 data format.
If you install 3.0 und run `--upgrade` you will get 3.0 data format.
Note: You cannot downgrade. Once on 3.0 you cannot go back to 2.8. So make sure that you create a backup copy of the data folders, just in case.